# How to use Gurobi?

Tags: julia, gurobi

I want to use Gurobi in a program like so:

```
use Gurobi
```

To which get the following error message:

```
ERROR: LoadError:     Gurobi not properly installed. Please run Pkg.build("Gurobi"). For
    more information go to https://github.com/jump-dev/Gurobi.jl

Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] top-level scope at /Users/prikshetsharma/.julia/packages/Gurobi/P6eVP/src/Gurobi.jl:7
 [3] include(::Function, ::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:380
 [4] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:368
 [5] top-level scope at none:2
 [6] eval at ./boot.jl:331 [inlined]
 [7] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:467
 [8] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /Users/prikshetsharma/.julia/packages/Gurobi/P6eVP/src/Gurobi.jl:4
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile Gurobi [2e9cd046-0924-5485-92f1-d5272153d98b] to /Users/prikshetsharma/.julia/compiled/v1.5/Gurobi/do9v6_rMyJO.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1305
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:1030
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:928
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:923
 [6] include(::Function, ::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:380
 [7] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:368
 [8] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:296
 [9] _start() at ./client.jl:506
in expression starting at /Users/prikshetsharma/Documents/clotorch/src/clotorch/flight/opt.jl:
```

When installing Gurobi itself, I get the following error, mentioning a problem with installation and steps to remedy it:

````
Pkg.build("Gurobi")
   Building Gurobi → `~/.julia/packages/Gurobi/P6eVP/deps/build.log`
┌ Error: Error building `Gurobi`: 
│ ERROR: LoadError: Unable to locate Gurobi installation. If the advice above did not help,
│ open an issue at https://github.com/jump-dev/Gurobi.jl and post the full
│ print-out of this diagnostic attempt.
│ 
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
│  [2] top-level scope at /Users/prikshetsharma/.julia/packages/Gurobi/P6eVP/deps/build.jl:161
│  [3] include(::String) at ./client.jl:457
│  [4] top-level scope at none:5
│ in expression starting at /Users/prikshetsharma/.julia/packages/Gurobi/P6eVP/deps/build.jl:155
│ 
│ **Unable to locate Gurobi installation. Running some common diagnostics.**
│ 
│ Gurobi.jl only supports the following versions:
│ 
│  - gurobi90
│  - gurobi91
│ 
│ Did you download and install one of these versions from gurobi.com?
│ Installing Gurobi.jl via the Julia package manager is _not_ sufficient!
│ 
│ Found GUROBI_HOME =  /Library/gurobi910/mac64/
│ 
│ Does this point to the correct install location?
│ 
│ We're going to look for the Gurobi library in this directory:
│     /Library/gurobi910/mac64/lib
│ 
│ That directory has the following files:
│ 
│ Aha! We tried looking in `/Library/gurobi910/mac64/lib`, but something went wrong. Are
│ you sure that your GUROBI_HOME environment variable is correct?
│ When combined with the appropriate suffix (e.g., `lib` or
│ `bin`, it needs to point to a valid directory.
│ 
│ 
│ You should set the `GUROBI_HOME` environment variable to point to the
│ install location then try again. For example (updating the path to the
│ correct location if needed):
│ ```
│ # On Windows, this might be
│ ENV["GUROBI_HOME"] = "C:\\Program Files\\gurobi910\\win64\\"
│ import Pkg
│ Pkg.add("Gurobi"
│ Pkg.build("Gurobi")
│ 
│ # On OSX, this might be
│ ENV["GUROBI_HOME"] = "/Library/gurobi910/mac64/"
│ import Pkg
│ Pkg.add("Gurobi")
│ Pkg.build("Gurobi")
│ 
│ # On Unix, this might be
│ ENV["GUROBI_HOME"] = "/opt/gurobi910/linux64/"
│ import Pkg
│ Pkg.add("Gurobi")
│ Pkg.build("Gurobi")
│ ```
│ **Note: your path may differ. Check which folder you installed the Gurobi
│ binary in, and update the path accordingly.**
└ @ Pkg.Operations /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:949
````

I've already following the steps mentioned for macOS in the above trace, but I still get the above error. How to install Gurobi and use it successfully?

Comment: Just a comment: you should be doing `using Gurobi` and not `use Gurobi` FWIW

Comment: Just to check, you actually installed Gurobi in the path you supplied? Gurobi is a commercial product and requires that you obtain a license: https://github.com/jump-dev/Gurobi.jl#installation

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the standalone Gurobi package first. Please follow the [instructions in these guides](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/quickstart.html) for more info. As was already mentioned in the comments, you should also acquire a license to run Gurobi.